# Pyautogui locateOnScreen handling when the searched image is not present

Tags: pyautogui

I am trying to make multiple screenshots in software, and sometimes the software displays an error message.
When that message appears, I would like to click it (instead of making a screenshot) and move to the next part to make a screenshot of.

I am using Pyautogui to do it, as it has been very useful before. But this time, because of this error message displayed, I have trouble handling it.
Pyautogui has a feature to locate a specific part on the screenshot, but when it is not there, instead of giving a False, it creates an error.

My first idea was to use an if statement, but the absence of the searched image makes the program crash, and I tried the try/except combo, but now it's making some kind of useless loop.

Could you have a look at my current code and help me fix it?

```
import time
import pyautogui

counter = 0
dimensions = (50,0,1000,1000)

time.sleep(5) # waiting 5 seconds before taking screenshots

while counter < 10 :
    time.sleep(1) # waiting 1 second

    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=dimensions)
    filename = str(counter) +"_PAGE1" + ".png" 
    im.save(filename) # saves the screenshot in a file

    time.sleep(1) # waiting 1 second
    pyautogui.press('enter') #make the software go the next page


    try
        pyautogui.locateOnScreen('errormessage.png'):
        pyautogui.press('enter') #click OK on the error message
        pyautogui.press('up') #go to the next line in the software
        counter += 1
        continue #to start over the while loop
    except:
        pass

    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=dimensions)
    filename = str(counter) +"_PAGE2" + ".png"
    im.save(filename) # saves the screenshot in a file

    time.sleep(1) # waiting 1 second
    pyautogui.press('escape') #go back to previous page
    pyautogui.press('up') #go to the next line in the software
    counter += 1
```

So I start on 1 line in the software, take a screenshot, hit enter. At this point, either an error message appears, then I want to click OK on it, and move to the next line (up), increment the counter and start over the while loop. Either the next page displays, I want to take a screenshot, and hit escape to go back, and move to the next line (up), increment the counter and start over the while loop.

As I said above, I tried a few different variants, without success so far. (putting the code in the except instead of the "pass", using an if statement...)

I hope my explanation is clear enough. As you can see I am pretty much a beginner in Python, but I try to improve my skills and your help will be very much appreciated.

cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a bunch of stuff, I finally found a workaround.
I did use an if statement, and a dirty trick :

```
if str(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('errormessage.png')) != "None":
```

And it does the job just right!

enjoy life!